# Using PHP to convert video files to mp4, flv, webgl, webm, ogv, etc

Tags: video, youtube, html5-video, video-processing, video-encoding

are there any functions or scripts available that allows for a video (either in a folder or on upload) to be converted to different filytypes so that they may be viewed in all types of systems?

I know youtube does this so that HTML5 compatible browsers don't watch flash versions of the files.

Where do I start learning this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into ffmpeg and php.

Or purchase a library from [here](http://codecanyon.net/item/php-ffmpeg-video-converter/124123)

pretty nice tutorial [here](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Video-Conversion-With-FFMPEG.html) actually!

Answer (score 0):

You can use FFMPEG class. Includes video converter, screen capture, video and audio bit rate, etc. [click here](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7764-PHP-Manipulate-video-files-with-the-FFMPEG-program.html) to download